# How can I write an ISO 8601 date with a timezone but no time component

Tags: date, datetime, language-agnostic, iso8601, timezone-offset

An [ISO 8601 datetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations) with a timezone is formatted like this:

```
2018-09-07T05:28:42Z
```

However, I need to represent some dates in my system where the precision is days, not seconds, which means that it would be an [ISO 8601 calendar date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Calendar_dates). Calendar dates are formatted like this:

```
2018-09-07
```

In the Wikipedia article about the standard (I don't have access to the standard itself, as you have to pay for that privilege), there is no mention of timezone when discussing dates. It does talk about omitting parts of the time:

> Either the seconds, or the minutes and seconds, may be omitted from the basic or extended time formats for greater brevity but decreased accuracy: [hh]:[mm], [hh][mm] and [hh] are the resulting reduced accuracy time formats.

From this, it seems that you cannot omit hours, so I could not write a calendar date like this:

```
2018-09-07TZ
```

It appears that the best I can do is truncating down to the hour:

```
2018-09-07T00Z
```

I don't want to do this if I can avoid it, however, as I am adding more precision to a date than is really there. The date means "sometime during the day of 07 September, 2018 in the UTC timezone", not "sometime during the midnight hour of 07 September, 2018 in the UTC timezone".

Any suggestions?

Comment: A date has no time zone (because there is no time that needs to be mapped to a time zone)

Comment: Though the use is debatable, a format like `2011-12-03+01:00` or `2018-09-07Z`(no `T`)  has been seen, see for example [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE). What do you need it for? If you have a good use case and the relevant parties agree, I think I’d go for it and not be too worried whether it conforms with ISO 8601 or not.

Comment: [The link I provided](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE) is to the Java built-in `ISO_OFFSET_DATE` formatter. Quote: “The ISO date formatter that formats or parses a date with an offset, such as '2011-12-03+01:00'.
This returns an immutable formatter capable of formatting and parsing the ISO-8601 extended offset date format.” So they seem to think that it does agree with ISO 8601. Whether they misread the sources or you did I dare not tell.

Comment: [Another example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48418975/how-to-convert-string-to-date-with-timezone)

Comment: Could you explain whats the usecase of a date with a timezone for you?

Comment: A date with a timezone is necessary in some cases because the time zone adds precision that is not possible with the date alone. This is useful if we know WHERE an event happened, but only know what day it was at that location. For a time zone in Japan, for example, "some time during the day on January 1 2020" includes a different subset of time than California "some time during the day on January 1 2020", because the days don't begin and end at the same time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Officially, the ISO 8601 spec does not allow for a date with a time zone unless a time is provided.  Thus, if you wish to remain ISO 8601 compliant, you cannot provide additional information for date-only values than year, month, and day (without resorting to time intervals - mentioned further below).

One format that *does* allow for this is XML Schema (aka "XSD"), in the [`xs:date`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#date) type.  There, it is optional, and would immediately follow the day, such as `2018-09-07Z`.  The XSD spec calls out in [Section D.3 Deviations from ISO 8601 Formats](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#deviantformats):

> **D.3.4 Time zone permitted**
>   The lexical representations for the
>   datatypes date, gYearMonth, gMonthDay, gDay, gMonth and gYear permit
>   an optional trailing time zone specificiation.

I realize you weren't asking about XSD, but this the only normative reference I'm aware of that's freely available online that calls out the time zone on a date is a deviation from ISO 8601.

As others have pointed out - thinking about a date with a time zone is a tricky thing.  In many aspects, a date-only value is ambiguous.  Consider if I presented you a calendar such as this one:

[image: calendar image]

Pointing at any given date on this calendar doesn't tell me anything about time zones.  I can give the calendar to someone in a different time zone and they will still be able to talk about dates.  It's simply that if we both point at "today" simultaneously, we *might* not be pointing at the same date.  Thus, time zones only apply when we apply a time context, whether "now" or a specific one.

However, we do tend to rationalize about all points in time on a given day in terms of a time zone.  In your example, the "UTC Day".  We mean that it runs from `T00:00Z` of one day, to just before `T00:00Z` of the next.  This is generally the reasoning behind things like `xs:date` allowing a time zone offset.

If we wanted to be strictly ISO 8601 compliant and represent the same meaning, we'd have to provide a range of date+time values, which are called "time intervals" in section 4.4 of the ISO 8601 spec, and are separated with a forward slash (`/`) character.  An example of such a value would be `2018-09-07T00:00Z/2018-09-08T00:00Z`.  However, be careful because ISO 8601 says *nothing* about whether the end date should be interpreted inclusively or exclusively.  [More on that here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48696238/634824).

Another ISO 8601 representation of an interval allows for a start time and a *duration* component, such as `2018-09-07T00:00Z/P1D`.  This feels to me like the closest fully ISO 8601 compliant way to represent a whole date interpreted in UTC.

Still, personally, if I needed to convey time zone with a date, I would use `2018-09-07Z` even if it wasn't strictly compliant.  Just make sure all consumers of your data agree on this format.  If you can't do that, just pass `2018-09-07` and name your field something like `utcDate`.

Answer (score 0):

The primary question here seems (to me) what you're using to write out your date/time.

Just for example, in C++ you could do:

```
time_t n = std::time(NULL);

tm *now = std::localtime(&n);

std::cout << std::put_time(now, "%F %z") << '\n';
```

This produces an output like:

```
2018-09-07 -0700
```

If your real question is whether this corresponds to a format specified in ISO 8601, I believe the answer is no. But it's fairly easy to produce it nonetheless.

Oh, and at least IMO, yes just a date with a time-zone can make perfectly good sense. Even though you only care about the date, the time zone tells you when that date begins/ends relative to other places on earth, so if I say "1 January 2019 PDT", somebody in (say) London knows that the date in question is offset by 7 hours from his local date.

Answer (score -6):

A date with a timezone makes no sense, because timezones adjust the hours/minutes within a day. Maybe you have a date and a separate timezone that you need for something different? For the case that you need the timezone for the international date line, you also need the time in format of hours:minutes without that the timezone would not make sense.

Btw. the W3C has also some examples about ISO8601 [Date and Time Formats](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime).
Last but not least you can always write your own parser for example with [Antlr](http://www.antlr.org/).

Also keep in mind that timezones might/will change over time - for example normal time vs. summer time.